# UIButton in Swift is not registering touches

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift

I'm trying to create a UIButton using Swift. It compiles fine and I can see my button in the simulator, but when I click it, nothing happens. This is the code I am using:

```
let settings = UIButton()
settings.addTarget(self, action: "touchedSet:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
settings.setTitle("Settings", forState: .Normal)
settings.frame = CGRectMake(0, 530, 150, 50)
scrollView.addSubview(settings)
```

In the same class, here is the function 'touchedSet':

```
func touchedSet(sender: UIButton!) {
    println("You tapped the button")
}
```

I'm using the simulator as I don't have an iOS 8.0 device, could that be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a random comment but I really don't like the name `settings` for a button. Even just doing `settingsButton` would be better :)

Comment: I tried your code. for me action method is getting called

Comment: Hmm, does it work for you in the simulator? I don't have access to an 8.0 device.

Comment: Yeah in simulator. Some times it wont recognise the selector there is a bug it seems. Even i faced not for your code , then i just changed the  action name (selector). It works

Answer (score 21):

I see it is an old question but I just faced very similar problem yesterday. My buttons were highlighted on touch but not firing the action.

I have two view controllers. One view covers the others view and button is on the top view.

eg.

- Rootviewcontroller has back view
- Topviewcontroller has top view

The button on top view does not call the action if I don't add the topviewcontroler as childviewcontroller of the rootviewcontroller. After adding the topviewcontroller as childviewcontroller it started to working.

So in short: just try to add the view controller of buttons superview as childviewcontroller to the parent views viewcontroller with the following method

```
func addChildViewController(_ childController: UIViewController)
```

Comment: I love you, Mert.  This killed about 6 hours of my time trying to figure out, and I finally found the answer here.

Comment: This! My UITapgestures and button delegates weren't working. Adding as a childVC did the trick. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Another SO gem! Thanks Mert!

Answer (score 11):

Selectors are a struct that have to be created.

Do it this way...

### Updated for Swift 4

```
settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hmm... try changing the button to var

Comment: I tried that; that didn't work. Someone above said my code worked for them, could the problem be that I'm using the simulator instead of a real device?

Comment: I'm also in simulator, just trying now

Comment: @Phillip try restarting Xcode or the simulator. It's working fine for me,

Comment: Hm, is there any special view I should be attatching it to? Right now I'm attatching it to self.view in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Phillip in the code you put in the question you're adding it to `scrollView` not `self.view`. Also, in Swift you don't need to use `self.` if it's obvious what you're referring to so just use `view.addSubview(settingsButton)`

Comment: This answer is simply wrong, because a string does the same as the corresponding selector in Swift.

Comment: @returntrue did you try it or are you just saying that because I've used this before and it works.

Comment: I did not try your answer corresponding to the question. But I have tried (and it is also stated in the documentation) that it makes no difference to use `Selector` instead of string.

Comment: @returntrue fair enough. Just looking at the dates of the question and answers. My answer was given 2 days after the beta anouncement of Swift. I'm not 100% sure but I reckon that when I gave my answer it was correct. Seeing as Swift didn't reach 1.0 until September it changed a number of times before then.

Comment: Okay you could be right. I didn't realize this and don't exactly know the behavior of Swift at this time.

Comment: But for now, the answer is outdated.

Comment: @ShahbazAkram this is from 2014. Selectors are now created in a different way. Will update. Check it now.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else doing manual view layout running into this issue, you might have defined your subview like such:

```
let settingsButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    // do some more setup
    button.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

The error lies with the fact that you are adding a target and passing `self` before it is actually available.

**This can be fixed in two ways**

1. Making the variable `lazy` and still adding the target in the initialization block:

   ```
   lazy var button: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton(type: .system)
       // since this variable is lazy, we are guaranteed that self is available
       button.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
       return button
    }()
   ```
2. Adding the target after your parent view has been initialized:

   ```
   init() { 
       self.settingsButton = .init(type: .system)
       super.init(frame: .zero)
       self.settingsButton.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(openSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
   }
   ```

Comment: Your answer is just Gold. I was doing the same mistake and debugging for hours. This is common sense but hard to get that issue is with `self`. Thanks :)

Comment: I hate that I only saw your comment after coming here to comment the same!

Comment: This is it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

In the simulator, sometimes it doesn't recognise the selector. There is a bug it seems. I just changed the action name (selector), and it worked.

```
let buttonPuzzle:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 400, 100, 50))
buttonPuzzle.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
buttonPuzzle.setTitle("Puzzle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
buttonPuzzle.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
buttonPuzzle.tag = 22;
self.view.addSubview(buttonPuzzle)
```

Selector Function is Here:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var btnsendtag:UIButton = sender
    if btnsendtag.tag == 22 {
        //println("Button tapped tag 22")
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who are also stuck in the tutorial:

I ran in to the same problem, when I was following Apple's "Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)". It turned out that I had overlooked these code lines in the tutorial:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
}
```

Adding them to my RatingControl fixed the problem.

Comment: This was what happened to me too. If you're following the tutorial, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39088964/1442743) question also provides answers on why the override is different in Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks. I have same problem with you.

Comment: @ouven +hero point - thanks! Do you know why not setting this property causes this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I have had this problem when parent view of my button has `isUserInteractionEnabled == false`. All subviews will have the same `userInteraction` as their parent view. So I have just added this line         `parentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and the problem disappeared. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when i had a subViewController with buttons and tapHandlers to match, and I wanted to place this to a stack in a separate superViewController..

This cause none of the tapHandlers to to trigger, and the solution was to instead of only using addArrangedSubview(subViewController.view), I also used `addChildViewController(subViewController)` in the superview to allow the childViewController to continue to operate as a viewController and not just a view.

Answer (score 1):

So you should use following line

```
settings.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: `UIButton.userInteractionEnabled`'s default value is `true`, so I doubt that this will fix it.

Comment: in my case, that property was mistakenly false. Thanks for reminding

Comment: @NaveedAhmad :)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but thought I'd give some help to other looking for this issue. First off, I'm not entire sure this is correct so please correct me if I'm wrong.

But if you set the selector wrongly the application would crash when you press the button since it's subscribed to a selector which doesn't exist. Which means that your selector is working. My guess is that something else is blocking the touch event, assuming `UIButton.enabled = true` and `UIButton.userInteractionEnabled = true`. Usually you could check this by long pressing the button and see if it hits. If it does then you have a `UIGestureRecognizer` added somewhere which takes up the hits first. Could also be the `UIScrollView` which is delaying the touch input (there's a checkbox for this in the Inspector).

Hope this helps someone, and hope it's accurate.

Comment: thanks for the idea. but my problem was that the method was called - `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when implementing UIButton and SearchBar on container view(UIView).
In my case, the cause was the constraint issue. Constraint to searchBar had issue and because of this, function set had never been called.

You can see if there's any from "Debug View Hierarchy" button. (constraint problem is shown as purple warning)

(env: iOS12, xcode10.1)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I just ran into the same issue on the very latest versions of iOS/Xcode (v12.4 / v10.3).  Turns out the issue for me was a LayoutConstraint!  No joke.  I had a leading label with the uiSwitch to the right, and found that I needed to change the constraints between the two such that it wasn't a fixed constant value of 8 points (Label-8-Switch-0-|).

As soon as I changed this to a ">=" the Switch was able to change states between on/off.  Laughably, it's almost like it wasn't able to change because it needs "room" (that apparently varies) to make the change with.

Not sure, but file it away as one of those "hummmm?" items in your memory.

One other item (that really shouldn't matter, frankly) is the valueChanged and tappedUpInside were both not firing (true on both an actual handset and on the simulators).  Also, they were hooked up through a storyboard.  But, this shouldn't matter as far as I know.

Comment: Just had this issue and your post helped me! It is strange that just a missing constraint can cause a button not to respond. In my case it was not centered but still be visible but not responding to touches. IB shows a warning but I would never had the idea this waring will cause this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was the view had top constraint, but not left/right and height constraints. So, the view was shrinking to 1x1 and it was not passing the touch event to children.

By adding more constraints, the children now getting the touch event and working ...

```
let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
viewHeader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
viewHeader.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
viewHeader.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewHeader,
                                          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
                                          relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                                          toItem: nil,
                                          attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute,
                                          multiplier: 1,
                                          constant: 44)
viewHeader.addConstraints([heightConstraint])
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I also found myself stuck with an unresponding button. I simply changed my initialisation from

```
let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
```

to

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link you button with your IBOutlet instance variable in your code if you're using storyboard.

Comment: I'm not using Interface Builder

Comment: I copied the exact code you posted into my project and it worked just fine... Do you have anything else added as subview of the scrollView after you set up the button? Or do you have some special setup for your scrollView?

Comment: The issue is that you used `let settings = UIButton()` instead of `var settings = UIButton()` when you declare the property. `let` variables are like `const` objects in Objective-C. I changed it to `var` then it worked.

Comment: Hm, even when its a var it still doesn't work :(
This may be a stupid question, but why would making it a constant cause it to stop working? I'm not reassigning it anywhere

Comment: Actually... I just tried it with `let` and it still worked... I'll see what I can find and post back...

Comment: I created a new view controller file in my project, copied all your code into it and imported all those yahoo weather parser class. Assigned the new view controller file to the view in storyboard and tested it in simulator everything worked just fine... I think this can indicate that your code has no problem. Is there anything special you've done to other part of your project? Other than that, I'm also clueless right now...

Comment: I've found what I think might be part of the same problem; see how I'm attaching everything to a scroll view? Well, when I click/drag in the simulator, it doesn't scroll. I am now 99% sure that the simulator is not recognizing my touches/clicks.

Comment: The reason why your scrollView doesn't scroll is that you haven't set a content size for it. I used `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width*1.5, self.view.bounds.size.height*1.5)` and it can be scrolled with no problem... And plus, the button still works...

Comment: Yeah, you are correct there. The view scrolls fine in the simulator, but when I push the button, nothing happens still :(

Comment: Have you been able to make it work? If still not, one thing I think worth trying is to copy your code for the view controller to a new project and see if it works... That way you'll know if there's anything wrong with your project settings.

Comment: I tried copy/pasting into a new project, that didn't fix it. However, add the line `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true` fixed it. For some weird reason it was disabled by default (?) Thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: @Phillip hmmmm that's so weird... Anyway, I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: Thanks! :D You can see the finished product here: www.github.com/codyd51/cumulus

Answer (score 0):

I can see only one problem: You have to set the `action` with `Selector` as following:

```
settings.addTarget(self, action: Selector("touchedSet:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Don't forget to insert `:` if you need to pass parameters to the function.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong, because a string does the same as the corresponding selector in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You said within the same class. Make sure that the button code itself is in the viewDidLoad() and the action be outside of it but inside the class if you are working with a view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that tutorial from Apple is the way they put the UIView (RatingControl) inside the StackView, which is incorrect. The UIView (RatingControl) should be outside of the StackView. So, the solution is:
1. Drag the UIView (RatingControl) outside of the StackView
2. Set the constraints for the new position of the RatingControl
   - Leading margin to the Container equal zero
   - Trailing margin to the Container equal zero
   - Top margin to the StackView equal zero

With this new constraints, now the RatingControl will have the same with as the Container, no matter what is the device screen size, and always will be just behind of the StackView where the photo selector will appear.

I hope this help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've found similar example for Swift 2 and adapted for Swift 3. Tested it is working very well. I hope it helps.

```
// http://lab.dejaworks.com/ios-swift-3-playground-uibutton-action
// Trevor D. Beydag

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
class Responder : NSObject {
    func action() {
        print("Button pressed!")
    }
}

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0,    height: 600.0))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
let responder = Responder()

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
button.setTitle("TEST", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(responder, action: #selector(Responder.action), for: .touchUpInside)
containerView.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the height and width constraints to 0, for some reason I needed to do this so it showed correctly on a multipurpose view for one use case, the buttons were visible but the touch stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a transparent `UIView` above the `UIButton` in the view hierarchy, which is why when I was "clicking on the `UIButton`", I was actually clicking on the transparent `UIView` on top of it.

Sending the transparent `UIView` back using `parentUIView.sendSubviewToBack(transparentUIView)` worked for me, because after doing this the `UIButton` came on top of the view hierarchy. Click on the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode to check if the `UIButton` is on top or not.

Comment: In my case the `navigationContentView` was over the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're **using Autolayout** to build your UI, **make sure to declare all your constraints** in your view and parent views.

Some times we forget to set all of them and the system complains about it, drawing your UI but not responding correctly in your touch events.

In my case, i’ve forgot to set my bottom constraint in my view so  i’m here to set this comment as a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

When a view like a button is placed next to another view like an image view etc. especially if if the image view is on top of another view Xcode sometimes thinks that your button is underneath that image view even though it is not. Sometimes you need to clear all the constraints and reset all constraints in order for the button to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).