# addTarget not working for UIButton created in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, addtarget

So, I've created a UIButton using Swift, and I animate it and it's superview using the following code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      //create a UIView to contain buttons. Set background color to nil, so it's transparent.
      var controlsView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:400, height:400));
      controlsView.alpha = 1.0
      controlsView.backgroundColor = nil

      //create a button and add some attributes. Self explanatory
      var loginButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
      loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 40.0, 200, 60)
      loginButton.alpha = 0.0
      loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: .Normal)
      loginButton.titleColorForState(.Normal)
      loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
      loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
      loginButton.layer.borderColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [0.827, 0.325, 0.0, 1.0])
      loginButton.addTarget(self, action: "loginPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

      //add the button to the view created to hold it
      controlsView.addSubview(loginButton)

      //now test blurring the background view. Create a UIVisualEffectView to create the blur effect. New in iOS7/8
    /*
      var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
      visualEffectView.frame = self.introImage.bounds
      self.introImage.addSubview(visualEffectView)
      visualEffectView.alpha = 0.0
    */

      //add the controls subview to the image view already here.
      self.introImage.addSubview(controlsView)

      //loginButton.addTarget(self, action: "loginButtonWasPressed:",forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)


      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7,
        animations: {
            loginButton.alpha = 1.0
            loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 100.0, width: 200, height: 60)
            //visualEffectView.alpha = 0.5
        },
        completion:nil)
    }
```

That's working fine. Then I created a function which should be called on touchUpInside of the button I created above:

```
    @IBAction func loginPressed(sender:UIButton){
      var alertView = UIAlertView();
      alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok");
      alertView.title = "title";
      alertView.message = "message";
      alertView.show();
    }
```

When I touch the button, the function DOES NOT fire. Can anyone help? I'm testing this on an actual device (iPhone 6 Plus/iOS 8.1.1

Comment: Did you set `userInteractionEnabled = true` for your `introImage`?

Comment: No, I did not, initially. I've tried your suggestion, and it seems to have worked, @Swipesight. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: set userInteractionEnabled to true works for me!

Comment: Please check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37706494/1416824

Answer (score 0):

To add an action to a button, you need to use the following code

```
loginButton.addTarget(self,action:#selector(loginPressed),
forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

This code is working fine for me.
For more detail you can follow this [[Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift][1])

Thanks.