# Swift - UIButton event not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am in the process of recoding my PUREMVC based apps from objective-c into Swift.

I am now creating a form and submit button, but none of any of the events it firing. Neither the textfields being edited, not the button being pressed. The keyboard on the textfields still appear on touch, but no events are getting triggered. Here is my code:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    var emailTF: UITextField!
    var passwordTF: UITextField!
    var submitBTN: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        // EMAIL
        self.emailTF = ViewElements.formTextField(FORM_DEFAULT_USERNAME)
        self.emailTF.tag = 100
        self.view.addSubview(self.emailTF)

        // PASSWORD
        self.passwordTF = ViewElements.formTextField(FORM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD)
        self.passwordTF.tag = 200
        self.view.addSubview(self.passwordTF)

        // SUBMIT
        self.submitBTN = ViewElements.formButtonSubmit(FORM_SUBMIT_TEXT)
        self.submitBTN.tag = 300
        self.submitBTN.addTarget(self, action: "pressedButton", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.submitBTN.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.submitBTN)


        // layout

        let tX = (SCREENWIDTH-NAVI_WIDTH)*0.5
        let tY = SCREENHEIGHT*0.3

        self.emailTF.frame = CGRect(x: tX, y: tY-NAVI_HEIGHT*1.2, width: NAVI_WIDTH, height: NAVI_HEIGHT)

        self.passwordTF.frame = CGRect(x: tX, y: tY+NAVI_HEIGHT*0.2, width: NAVI_WIDTH, height: NAVI_HEIGHT)

        self.submitBTN.frame = CGRect(x: tX, y: tY+NAVI_HEIGHT*1.6, width: NAVI_WIDTH, height: NAVI_HEIGHT)


        // events
        self.emailTF.delegate = self
        self.passwordTF.delegate = self

        print("---1---")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
    visualEffectView.frame = self.introImage.bounds
    self.introImage.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    visualEffectView.alpha = 0.0
    */

    // FORM EVENTS


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
      print ("---")
    }

    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print ("---")
        return false
    }


    func pressedButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("::")
    }   
}
```

In case you want to see the Util I use to create the elements:

```
class func formTextField(myText: String) -> UITextField
{
    let newTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: NAVI_WIDTH, height: NAVI_HEIGHT));
    newTextField.text = myText as String
    newTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    newTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(UIColor.whiteColor())(0.5)
    newTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    return newTextField
}

class func formButtonSubmit(myText: String) -> UIButton
{
    let newButton: UIButton = UIButton()
    newButton.setTitle(myText, forState: .Normal)
    newButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    newButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "InterstateCondensed", size: 45)
    newButton.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    newButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
    newButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(UIColor.whiteColor())(0.8)
    newButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: NAVI_WIDTH, height: NAVI_HEIGHT)

    return newButton
}
```

Really bizarre that no event is firing. Anyone?

Comment: have you added selector to your control?

Comment: After trying all of teh below and nothing helped, I copied the whole view code into a new swift project and everything works. So I am not insane yet. But the question is, what stops the viewcontroller from behaving like this? I want this to work within my PuremVC framework.

Comment: how are you connecting this to your story board?

Comment: @MarcusKirsch are you sure nothing overlays the button ?

Comment: Please checkout my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37706494/1416824

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Selector` when calling an action.

```
self.submitBTN.addTarget(self, action: Selector("pressedButton"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

For the textField problems (and I'm guessing here) the problem could be that you are instatiating the delegate after adding the Subview.

```
    // PASSWORD
    self.passwordTF = ViewElements.formTextField(FORM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD)
    self.passwordTF.tag = 200
    self.passwordTF.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.passwordTF)

    // SUBMIT
    self.submitBTN = ViewElements.formButtonSubmit(FORM_SUBMIT_TEXT)
    self.submitBTN.tag = 300
    self.submitBTN.addTarget(self, action: "pressedButton", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.submitBTN.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.emailTF.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.submitBTN)
```

Comment: Tried Selector before and again. no difference. Also had delegate declaration up there, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `action: "pressedButton",` with `action: "pressedButton:",`

or try to remove the parameter of `pressedButton` method if you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `:` after the `pressedButton` this should fix your problem:

```
self.submitBTN.addTarget(self, action: Selector("pressedButton:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Also the almighty Xcode gave you `Storyboard` that will make your life much easier, you will not need to set all the parameters from code, even the delegate and data source is setted from it

Comment: Tried that, doesnt fix anything. I like to code y stuff, so I hate storyboards. I keep with one editor, pure and simple. Makes things cleaner and worked perfectly for me in all my objective-c projects.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I posted an answer. The issue is and was how I add my viewcontroller to teh window without using storyboards (which I dont like). All the above code ideas are right but dont fix my issue. I fixed it like this:

```
window.rootViewController = rootView
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Simple as that. Thanks Everyone.