# intrinsicContentSize() - Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I updated to Xcode 8 beta 5, and now get the following error on a class that inherits from UIView:

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass

override public func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize
{
   ...
}
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize).
(You can easily find it just putting the word "intrinsicContentSize" in the searchbar of [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com).)

> Declaration
>
> ```
> var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { get }
> ```

`intrinsicContentSize` has become a computed property, so you need to override it in this way:

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        //...
        return someCGSize
    }
}
```

Or simply:

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    //...
    return someCGSize
}
```

Comment: Is there any resource that lists the recent changes?

Comment: @GoldenJoe, there is [iOS 9.3 to iOS 10.0 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/index.html). But it's a huge list and I'd rather use seachbar than check the Diffs.

Comment: Thanks, did you just search for "iOS Diffs" or something to find this? It is huge, but it's nice to browse the things you use frequently.

Comment: @GoldenJoe, Diffs can be found in [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)(current) or [Guides and Sample Code](future version), with Resource Type "Release Notes". Please check.

Comment: Read the source file of `UIView` class you will see how it has been changed.

Answer (score 7):

While transitioning from one version of Xcode to another, there is different ways to find out why your code does not compile anymore. Here are a few resources for `intrinsicContentSize`:

1. You can search for `intrinsicContentSize` from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=intrinsicContentSize).
2. You can search for `intrinsicContentSize` straight from [Apple Developer API Reference page for UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview).
3. You can open the [iOS 10.0 API Diffs for UIKit page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Swift/UIKit.html) and search for instances of `intrinsicContentSize` with your browser's *find menu* (shortcut: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).
4. You can search for `intrinsicContentSize` from Xcode's *Documentation and API Reference* (path: <kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>Documentation and API Reference</kbd>, shortcut: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>).
5. You can also right-click on any `UIView` initializer in your Xcode code (for example, `UIView()`), select <kbd>Jump to Definition</kbd> and then perform a search for `intrinsicContentSize`.

---

These searches will show you that `intrinsicContentSize`, with Swift 3 and iOS 10, is no more a method but a computed property of `UIView` that has the following declaration:

> `var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { get }`

---

As a consequence, you will have to replace your `intrinsicContentSize()` method implementation with the following code snippet:

```
override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return ...
}
```